# How do I simply copy and paste a piece of data into another page on the same spreadsheet on google sheets script editor?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I just want to get my porfolio value on page "COVER PAGE" of my spreadsheet and copy that onto another sheet called "IGNORE" everyday at around 12am onto a list. I am new to script editor and I can't seem to find any resources that are simple enough to understand. Here is what I got so far:

```
function snapData() {
// get current sheet and tabs
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var counter = 4;

var history = ss.getSheetByName('COVER PAGE')
var database = ss.getSheetByName('IGNORE');

var price = history.getRange("D3").getValue;
var destination = database.getRange("Y3"+counter);

price.copyTo(destination);
counter++;
}
```

Comment: Couldn't you just use [`=IMPORTRANGE()`][Google Support Link]? [Google Support Link]: https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093340?hl=en-GB