# Simply Copying and Pasting data from D3 in spreadsheet "COVER PAGE" into any column in the spreadsheet "IGNORE"

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to use the script editor to copy my portfolio value in D3 on the spreadsheet"COVER PAGE" and paste that number daily into another column in spreadsheet "IGNORE".

I am new to script editor and having a hard time trying to code my way out of this problem. If someone can help or point me towards a useful resource, I would be very appreciative. I couldn't find anything beginner friendly for this problem on youtube.

Comment: Couldn't you just use [`=IMPORTRANGE()`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093340?hl=en-GB)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I simply copy and paste a piece of data into another page on the same spreadsheet on google sheets script editor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70500110/how-do-i-simply-copy-and-paste-a-piece-of-data-into-another-page-on-the-same-spr)

Answer (score 1):

#### Copy Paste

```
function copyPaste(col=1) {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const csh = ss.getSheetByName('COVERPAGE');
  const ish = ss.getSheetByName('IGNORE');
  const cv = csh.getRange(3,4).getValue();//source value
  ish.getRange(1,col,ish.getMaxRows()).setValue(cv);//entire column default column is 1
}
```